# Unable to fetch comma delimited values using in clause

Tags: mysql

hi i have a table with values of numbers delimited by commas the schema / field is as shown below

preferred_location - 0,161,186,263

preferred_location datatype is long text

i tried to get the rows which has preferred_location 161 by using the query below

```
 select * from tablename where preferred_location in(161)
```

But not getting any result

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select * from tablename where  find_in_set(preferred_location, '0,161,186,263') <> 0
```

Comment: How to pass multiple values example select * from tablename where find_in_set('161,168,234,678',preferred_location ) > 0

Comment: still i am not getting any results at all tried out updated query

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find_in_set()` in order to find the values in set,also if you can alter the schema then do normalize it, by having another junction table which holds the relation from this table to preferred_location table

```
select * from 
tablename 
where 
find_in_set('161',preferred_location ) > 0
```

**Edit from comments**
For multiple values like  `find_in_set('161,168,234,678',preferred_location ) > 0` no it can't be possible doing like this you have to perform for each location id like

```
select * from 
tablename 
where 
find_in_set('161',preferred_location ) > 0
and find_in_set('168',preferred_location ) > 0
and find_in_set('234',preferred_location ) > 0
and find_in_set('678',preferred_location ) > 0 ... for more
```

[Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

[find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: How to pass multiple values example     select * from 
tablename 
where 
find_in_set('161,168,234,678',preferred_location ) > 0

Answer (score 0):

This will for search in comma separated values in column:

```
select * from tablename where preferred_location LIKE %161,% OR LIKE %,161,% OR LIKE %161,% OR LIKE %,161%
```